# Export Tree Structure table to csv with formatting

Tags: javascript, json

I have a tree structure in my html table which is nested multi level

```
 Parent 
    --- Child1
           ----Parent
                   ---- Child
   - Child
```

SampleJSON:

I need to export the above data to CSV with a tree structure for the `Name` field, I attached the CSV image of how this data has to be extracted with column headers. for instance if i have 5 level of depth in the json i want the first 5 columns as Name and 6th column as Status and 7th column Country all data is present inline with column header

[![expected output][1]][1]

[Final CSV to be exported][1]

Comment: I have tried using json2csv for exporting the csv file data is getting exported but not able to achieve the formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to determine the maximum depth of the structure, then use a second recursive function to build your result, padding each row with comma-delimited cells along the way. Joining the array with newlines produces a CSV string.

Having said that, the structure you've presented isn't an actual tree nor a "JSON" object because there may be multiple roots in the outer array. If you're passing a `{id: 0, name: "", children: [ ... ]}` in as the outermost (root) element, then you're dealing with a real tree and will need to tweak the functions shown here slightly to work on that (work on the current node, then recurse on children if extant).

I also went ahead and added quotes around each field in case you might have commas in your data at some point.

```js
const data = [ { "id": "692953339134475108", "entityID": "5000231121", "Name": "*Test1", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND", "children": [ { "id": "699554426559363304", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "Testing 1", "entityID": "1416474126", "hierarchyId": "699154426559445604", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "697253339134484008", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*Test 2", "entityID": "1398417635", "hierarchyId": "697553339134529808", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "696253339134488908", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "Not Available", "entityID": "Not Available", "hierarchyId": "694653339134506008", "status": "Not Available", "date": "Not Available", "country": "Not Available" },{ "id": "691453339134493608", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*Test 3", "entityID": "1387487096", "hierarchyId": "691653339134511008", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "697053339134483308", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*TEst 5", "entityID": "1396529024", "hierarchyId": "694053339134516108", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "698653339134491308", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*test 6", "entityID": "1396474242", "hierarchyId": "695553339134503808", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "692053339134490708", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*test 7", "entityID": "1396505159", "hierarchyId": "699853339134497808", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "691054426559395204", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*atest 8", "entityID": "1416469729", "hierarchyId": "696954426559401304", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "696353339134489808", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*TWSTTTT", "entityID": "1396474493", "hierarchyId": "693853339134524908", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, 
{ "id": "697454426559390004", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*test9", "entityID": "1376584880", "hierarchyId": "698054426559423304", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND", "children": [ { "id": "698653991889575501", "parentId": "697454426559390004", "directPercent": "10", "totalPercent": "50", "Name": "Not Available", "entityID": "Not Available", "hierarchyId": "694453991889580001", "status": "Not Available", "date": "Not Available", "country": "Not Available" } ] }, { "id": "693653339134492808", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "Not Available", "entityID": "1376584880", "hierarchyId": "691153339134501508", "status": "Not Available", "date": "Not Available", "country": "Not Available" }, { "id": "696154426559394204", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*THE TEST", "entityID": "1416583295", "hierarchyId": "698854426559467404", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "692153339134481408", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*TESTT", "entityID": "1396477303", "hierarchyId": "691053339134522808", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "694553339134485108", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*TEDTTTETETE", "entityID": "1392671953", "hierarchyId": "698853339134513508", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" }, { "id": "696953339134492208", "parentId": "692953339134475108", "Name": "*TESSRTTT", "entityID": "1387487096", "hierarchyId": "696153339134518708", "status": "Active", "date": "-", "country": "IND" } ] } ];

const depth = (a, d=0) => {
  let deepest = d;
  
  for (const node of a) {
    if (node.children) {
      deepest = Math.max(deepest, depth(node.children, d + 1));
    }
  }
  
  return deepest;
};

const dataToCSV = (a, res, maxDepth, depth=0) => {
  for (const node of a) {
    const row = Array(maxDepth + 1).fill("")
      .concat([node.status, node.country])
    ;
    row[depth] = node.Name;
    res.push(row);
    
    if (node.children) {
      dataToCSV(node.children, res, maxDepth, 1 + depth);
    }
  }
  
  return res;
};

const body = dataToCSV(data, [], depth(data));
const headers = Array(body[0].length)
  .fill("\"Name\"")
  .concat(["\"status\"", "\"Country\""])
  .slice(2)
  .join(",") + "\n"
;
const csv = headers + body.map(
  e => e.map(cell => `"${cell}"`).join(",")
).join("\n");

console.log(csv);
```

Result CSV string in spreadsheet previewer:

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: your above example works perfectly for exporting a single column in to csv , if i try to add more columns the structure gets affected .

For Ex :

Comment: If you use commas inside an element, you need to add quotes around this so that they're not interpreted as different CSV cells, which breaks the formatting algorithm. If you want to make these comma-separated attributes part of the cellular structure, you need to multiply the depth by the number of commas in the structure. But these requirements aren't stated in your post; please update it with a complete example if the problem isn't already resolved and I can try to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: You'll need to post the actual structure you're working with. My post explains this--you have two roots in your "tree".

Comment: Sorry, that's not too helpful. Fiddles can go down over time, and I'd rather my code match the question here than something off-site. Please edit the above question to state your exact requirements and show the input, state the transformation you desire and expected output and let me know so I can update my answer for you. Thanks!

Comment: So you just want 3 rows in the output CSV? I'm still not very clear on what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear what you're asking. I see 17 nodes in the object and 6 in the spreadsheet. Why are some being ignored? Some cell contents in the spreadsheet don't exist in the object--where did `"UnActive"` come from? Without *exact* output with a clear explanation of how you got the output given an input, I can't simply invent or guess the rules you're following.

Comment: Sorry for confusing you ,  i have update the exact output what this json should produce when extracted to csv.